# Import data model into local dynamodb with NoSql Workbench

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql, data-modeling

How to import the data model created with nosql workbench then switch to local db in nosql workbench and import into it? In my situation, I created a table and attributes then added some data in the workbench then I turned on localdb and wanted to import what I had done into localdb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Commit to DynamoDB

First, click on the Visualizer tab for the table you wish to commit. Then click on `Commit to Amazon DynamoDB`:

[image]

Once there, if you have not already created a connection to DynamoDB Local, choose to create one. If you have already done so, select that connection:

[image]

Now simply click `Commit` and you're done. Be sure that DynamoDB Local is running at the time of clicking Commit.

Comment: HI, thanks for detailed answer and worked great, I have another question, I was able to put some data around 5000+ with node js script from MySQL database with a lots of non key attributes, but after I realized there is no option to modify or update data model now, I just need to add some index and alter/delete unnecessary attribute, and also scared that how can I export table with all data back to previous step? I actually wanted to make all lambda functions and test it before I commit to real aws.